# Missing data in MongoDB (Mongoose/MLab) after successful search using the same field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a very specific question. I have a web project that is using Express (Node.JS) and MLab (MongoDB/Mongoose). I've manually edited several records in a collection (yeah, I know, bad idea) and am using one of those fields in a Mongoose search. The schema is defined as follows: (relevant part only)

```
user: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Registration"
        },
        username: String,
        type: String
    }
```

My search is as follows:

```
Master.find({$or: [{'user.type': 'committee'}, {'user.type': 'admin'}]}, function(err, foundUsers) {
    do stuff
});
```

The search works just fine (using 'user.type'), but the user object in each record is undefined in foundUsers.

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I tried to pull a fast one and add something to the user record that wasn't in the Registration Schema. Mongo was smarter than I was in this case.